# Join 1 to Many from the same table and append to row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

SQL Server 2005

1 Table

```
ID Project_id   
-------------
1  1           
1  2           
1  2           
1  3
```

2 queries

1st query gets unique results based on the ID

```
ID 
---
1
2
3
4
5
```

2nd Query totals the number of project_id's by ID

```
ID Project_id total
--------------------
1  1          1
1  2          2
1  3          1
```

I'm trying to combine the queries so that the results are in one row like this

```
ID Project_id _1 Project_id_2 Project_id_3
-------------------------------------------
1  1             2            1
```

Is this possible?

Comment: That's not going to scale well when there are more projects associated.  Listing values down is more scalable.

Comment: I have to show the results across in a row on the report. There are about 5 project that each ID can have.

Comment: Also there are 1000's of ID's.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm afraid you are gonna have to use dynamic sql, so be sure to visit this [link](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) before. Once you did that, you can try this:

```
DECLARE @Project VARCHAR(MAX), @Query VARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @Project = COALESCE(@Project + ',', '') + QUOTENAME('Project_Id_' + CAST(Project_id AS VARCHAR))
FROM Project
GROUP BY Project_id

SET @Query = '
SELECT Id, '+@Project+'
FROM (SELECT Id, ''Project_Id_'' + CAST(Project_id AS VARCHAR) Project_Id, 1 AS Num FROM Project) P
PIVOT(SUM(Num) FOR Project_Id IN ('+@Project+')) PV'

EXEC(@Query)
```